# Calling a function when canvas zooming is done

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, location, zooming

I have a `UserControl` that contains a `Canvas`. The Canvas can be panned and zoomed in and out correctly. I also keep a small user control that shows the content of the big user control with a small rectangle that displays the user what he's currently looking at (The size / location of that rectangle is updated whenever the user pans / zooms on the main user control)

All is working correctly except for one thing - When I zoom in or out using the mouse wheel, the location of the small reference rectangle is updated to the wrong location, and when I pan the canvas around it shows the correct location. I calculated the location of the reference rectangle by taking the 0, 0 point of the canvas in the main user control and converting it to point on the screen. Here's my code:

```
public Point GetTopLeftOffset()
{
  Point topLeft = PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
  return m_mainCanvas.PointFromScreen(topLeft);
}
```

My idea was to call the above function when the zooming is actually done. My suspicion is that the code gets the top left offset while zooming is still performing - what causes the output to be wrong.

If anyone can tell me why the value is wrong when zooming in or out and how to fix this I would be really greatful!

Thanks!

Here's an image of something identical to what I'm working on: (Curtesy of WPF-Graphics.com)
[image: This is a WPF control showing a main image, and a small thumb with a viewport rectangle showing the user what he's looking at]

Comment: Can you please post more code plus a UI snapshot would be really helpful to understand what actually you are trying to do.

Comment: In the picture I added, what I want to implement is the white rectangle in the `ZoomPanelMiniMap` window